# Set a cell value based on duplicate rows in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to identify trends for a text value. Basically, if column B repeats "Apple" three or more times, have a cell in Column G changed to "yes". Ultimately, I'd like it to check for the last six months based on date in column E and have Column I list the Area values that are repeating. (Just identify the problem area)

[image: Example]

| Deficiency Number | Area | Process Name | Process Owner | Date Assigned | Date Closed | Repeat |  | Negative trend |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DF-2022-01 | MATERIAL | S-4 Emergency Response Trailer Invenory | XXX | 11/7/2022 |  |  |  | (examle MATERIAL) |

Having a column that counts the number of times each area repeats would work as well.

I appreciate any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

As far as I understood the task description, you need a formula using the [**IF() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) and the [**COUNTIFS() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)

`=IF(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B2,B2,$E$2:$E2,">" & EDATE(TODAY(),-3))>2,"YES","no")`

The `EDATE(TODAY(),-3)` part of the formula calculates a date three months earlier than today (see the descriptions of the [**EDATE() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edate-function-3c920eb2-6e66-44e7-a1f5-753ae47ee4f5) and the [**TODAY() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/today-function-5eb3078d-a82c-4736-8930-2f51a028fdd9))

Be careful when specifying addresses - the beginnings of the ranges **$B$2:** and **$E$2:** are absolute links, and the ends of the ranges are relative links, cells in the same columns and in the current row.